# Which moons do have neutrospheres?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, natural-satellites, magnetic-field

Or in other words: which moons do have ionospheres but not surface-bound ones? The space beneath an ionosphere is called a neutrosphere. I only know of Titan. I know that the Galilean moons and Triton also have ionospheres but do all of them have surface-bound ones or do they have neutrospheres too?